# fetching data from sqlite, error in WHERE clause

Tags: android, where-clause, android-sqlite

I don't know where i am going wrong, I am new to android development and trying some code with SQLITE database:

I have got a database named cards and a table in it named mycards 
my create statement is:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table mycards(card_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + NAME + " text not null, card_type text not null,json_string text not null);";
```

my insert function is as follows:

```
 public long insertCard(String name, String type, String json_string) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(TYPE, type);
initialValues.put(JSON, json_string);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


//here TYPE is card_type
```

in the card_type column there are three possible values Pcard, Bcard, Ccard.
when i want to retrieve data, I want it filtered on values (strings) in column card_type.

hence my fetch function is: (showing for one type only) :

```
 public Cursor fetchallPCards() {



  return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"card_name"},TYPE+"="+"Pcard", null, null, null, null);   

}
```

but iam getting error :

```
03-14 00:26:21.233: E/SQLiteLog(701): (1) no such column: Pcard
```

where have i gone wrong?
As far as my knowledge, I think I am right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the string in your query, try:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "card_name" }, TYPE + "=" + "'Pcard'", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `fetchallPCards` method to look like this:

```
public Cursor fetchallPCards() { 

   return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"card_name"},TYPE+"=?", 
                                    new String[] {"Pcard"}, null, null, null);   
}
```